# Problema para gravar chave estrangeira em tabela

Tags: java, html, spring, jpa, thymeleaf

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto java web - utilizando Spring , Thymeleaf , Html, Mysql . Neste projeto tenho duas classes que estão relacionadas por chave estrangeira. (Técnico e Cargo).

Na minha view (adicionarTecnico.html) criei um combobox utilizando select para buscar a lista de cargos, até ai tudo bem, está mostrando a relação de cargos certinho, mas quando é escolhido o cargo não está mandando as informações do registro selecionado para o POST do Controller (TecnicoController), o Cargo está indo vazio. Agradeço se alguém puder me ajudar. Vou colocar as informações abaixo:

CLASSE TÉCNICO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class Tecnico{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @Transient
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private int active;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @Column(name = "cpf")
    private String cpf;

    @Column(name = "matricula")
    private int matricula;

    @Column(name = "perfil")
    private String perfil;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Cargo cargo;

    // getters e setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Tecnico [id=" + id + ", email=" + email + ", password=" + password + ", nome=" + nome + ", active="
                + active + ", roles=" + roles + ", cpf=" + cpf + ", matricula=" + matricula + ", perfil=" + perfil
                + ", status=" + status + ", cargo=" + cargo + "]";
    }

}
```

CLASSE CARGO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cargo")
public class Cargo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int id;

    @Column(name = "descricao")
    public String descricao;

    @Column(name = "status")
    public String status;

    // getters e setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cargo [id=" + id + ", descricao=" + descricao + ", status=" + status + "]";
    }

}
```

CLASSE TECNICOCONTROLLER (só os métodos GET e POST da view adicionarTecnico.html):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/tecnico/adicionarTecnico", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView adicionar() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    carregarUsuarioLogado(modelAndView);

    Tecnico tecnico = new Tecnico();

    modelAndView.addObject("tecnico", tecnico);
    modelAndView.setViewName("/admin/tecnico/adicionarTecnico");

    List<Cargo> cargo = cargoService.findAllCargos();

    modelAndView.addObject("cargo", cargo);

    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/tecnico/adicionarTecnico", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView adicionar(@Valid Tecnico tecnico, Cargo cargo, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

    carregarUsuarioLogado(modelAndView);
    System.out.println("passou por aqui....");
    Tecnico tecnicoMatricula = tecnicoService.findTecnicoByMatricula(tecnico.getMatricula());
    System.out.println("passou por aqui.xxxx...");

    if (tecnicoMatricula != null) {
        bindingResult.rejectValue("matricula", "error.tecnico", "Esta matrícula já foi cadastrada");
    } 
    System.out.println("passou por aqui.yyyy...");

    Tecnico tecnicoCpf = tecnicoService.findTecnicoByCpf(tecnico.getCpf());

    if (tecnicoCpf != null) {
        bindingResult.rejectValue("cpf", "error.tecnico", "Este CPF já foi cadastrado");
    } 
    System.out.println("passou por aqui..zzzz..");

    Tecnico tecnicoEmail = tecnicoService.findTecnicoByEmail(tecnico.getEmail());

    if (tecnicoEmail != null) {
        bindingResult.rejectValue("email", "error.tecnico", "Este email já foi cadastrado");
    }
    System.out.println("passou por aqui..vvvvv..");

    if (!ValidarCpf.validarCpf(tecnico.getCpf())) {
        bindingResult.rejectValue("cpf", "error.tecnico", "Este cpf é inválido");
    }
    System.out.println("passou por aqui..cccc..");

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        modelAndView.setViewName("/admin/tecnico/adicionarTecnico");
    } else {        

        System.out.println(" id do cargo" + cargo.id); ////cargo.id com valor vazio
        System.out.println(" id do cargoxxx" + cargo); ////cargo com valor vazio
        System.out.println(" tecnico " + tecnico);
        //tecnico.setCargo(cargo);
        tecnico.setPassword("smas1234");
        System.out.println("passou por aqui..bbbbb..");

        //tecnicoService.saveTecnico(tecnico);

        System.out.println("passou por aqui...ttttt.");

        modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", "Técnico cadastrado com sucesso!");
        System.out.println("passou por aqui..rrrr..");

        //modelAndView.addObject("tecnico", new Tecnico());
    }
    return modelAndView;
}
```

VIEW ADICIONARTECNICO (só o select do combobox)

```
        <div class="box-body">                              
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                          <label for="exampleInputEmail">Cargos *</label> 
                  <select class="form-control" th:field="*{cargo.id}">
                                    <option th:each="cargo : ${cargo}" 
                                         th:value="${cargo.id}" th:selected="selected"
                                         th:utext="${cargo.descricao}"/>
                                         </select>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: Alguém se habilita???

Answer (score 0):

O ideal seria que você tivesse postado as tags do seu `form`, pois isso influencia em como os dados são enviados, mas basicamente, seu `form` deveria estar assim:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/admin/tecnico/adicionarTecnico}" th:object="${tecnico}" method="post">
```

E no seu controller, você recebe somente o objeto técnico:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/tecnico/adicionarTecnico", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView adicionar(@Valid Tecnico tecnico, BindingResult bindingResult) {
```

Entao você será capaz de acessar o `id` do cargo através do objeto técnico: `tecnico.getCargo().getId()`.